# lists match with dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to match lists with dataframe

```
> lists
    [[1]]
    [1] "SURFSKINTEMP=6" "MODIS_LST=1"   

    [[2]]
    [1] "TOTCO=13"    "MODIS_LST=1"

    [[3]]
    [1] "TOTCO=6"     "MODIS_LST=1"

    [[4]]
    [1] "TOTO3=15"    "MODIS_LST=1"

    [[5]]
    [1] "TOTH2OVAP=6" "MODIS_LST=1"

    [[6]]
    [1] "TOTH2OVAP=1" "MODIS_LST=1"
```

and the test dataframe

```
 > test
      LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG SURFSKINTEMP SURFAIRTEMP TOTH2OVAP TOTO3 TOTCO TOTCH4 OLR_ARIS CLROLR_ARIS OLR_NOAA MODIS_LST
    1     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-30 2015-01-06    2            6           6         6    16    13     13       10          10       10         1
```

in above example. data.frame match 3 lists

```
[1] "SURFSKINTEMP=6" "MODIS_LST=1" 
[1] "TOTCO=13"    "MODIS_LST=1"  
[1] "TOTH2OVAP=6" "MODIS_LST=1"
```

so the match count is 3, matching ratio is 3/6 = 50%.

my expect will add two columns(MATCH_COUNT  MATCH_RATIO), like:

```
  LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG SURFSKINTEMP SURFAIRTEMP TOTH2OVAP TOTO3 TOTCO TOTCH4  OLR_ARIS CLROLR_ARIS OLR_NOAA MODIS_LST  MATCH_COUNT  MATCH_RATIO          
1     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-30 2015-01-06    2            6           6         6    16    13     13        10          10       10         1            3          0.5
```

the list and test dataframe I used is:

```
lists <- list(c("SURFSKINTEMP=6", "MODIS_LST=1"), c("TOTCO=13", "MODIS_LST=1"
), c("TOTCO=6", "MODIS_LST=1"), c("TOTO3=15", "MODIS_LST=1"), 
    c("TOTH2OVAP=6", "MODIS_LST=1"), c("TOTH2OVAP=1", "MODIS_LST=1"
    ))



test <- structure(list(LONGITUDE = 118.5, LATITUDE = -11.5, DATE_START = structure(1419897600, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DATE_END = structure(1420502400, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), FLAG = 2, SURFSKINTEMP = 6L, SURFAIRTEMP = 6L, TOTH2OVAP = 6L, 
    TOTO3 = 16L, TOTCO = 13L, TOTCH4 = 13L, OLR_ARIS = 10L, CLROLR_ARIS = 10L, 
    OLR_NOAA = 10L, MODIS_LST = 1L), .Names = c("LONGITUDE", 
"LATITUDE", "DATE_START", "DATE_END", "FLAG", "SURFSKINTEMP", 
"SURFAIRTEMP", "TOTH2OVAP", "TOTO3", "TOTCO", "TOTCH4", "OLR_ARIS", 
"CLROLR_ARIS", "OLR_NOAA", "MODIS_LST"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

How to implement it, thanks

and for multi-rows

```
> test1
  LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG SURFSKINTEMP SURFAIRTEMP TOTH2OVAP TOTO3 TOTCO TOTCH4 OLR_ARIS CLROLR_ARIS OLR_NOAA MODIS_LST
1     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-30 2015-01-06    2            6           6         6    16    13     13       10          10       10         1
2     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-31 2015-01-07    2            1           6         1    16     6     14        4           4       10         1
3     118.5    -11.5 2015-01-01 2015-01-08    2           16           6        17    16     8      6        4           4       10         2
```

my expect is

```
  LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATE_START   DATE_END FLAG SURFSKINTEMP SURFAIRTEMP TOTH2OVAP TOTO3 TOTCO TOTCH4 OLR_ARIS CLROLR_ARIS OLR_NOAA MODIS_LST  MATCH_COUNT  MATCH_RATIO
1     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-30 2015-01-06    2            6           6         6    16    13     13       10          10       10         1            3          0.5
2     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-31 2015-01-07    2            1           6         1    16     6     14        4           4       10         1            2        0.333
3     118.5    -11.5 2015-01-01 2015-01-08    2           16           6        17    16     8      6        4           4       10         2            0            0
```

used data here is

```
test1 <- structure(list(LONGITUDE = c(118.5, 118.5, 118.5), LATITUDE = c(-11.5,                                                            
-11.5, -11.5), DATE_START = structure(c(1419897600, 1419984000,                                                                   
1420070400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), DATE_END = structure(c(1420502400,                                                 
1420588800, 1420675200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), FLAG = c(2,                                                             
2, 2), SURFSKINTEMP = c(6L, 1L, 16L), SURFAIRTEMP = c(6L, 6L,                     
6L), TOTH2OVAP = c(6L, 1L, 17L), TOTO3 = c(16L, 16L, 16L), TOTCO = c(13L,         
6L, 8L), TOTCH4 = c(13L, 14L, 6L), OLR_ARIS = c(10L, 4L, 4L),                     
    CLROLR_ARIS = c(10L, 4L, 4L), OLR_NOAA = c(10L, 10L, 10L),                   
    MODIS_LST = c(1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE",              
"DATE_START", "DATE_END", "FLAG", "SURFSKINTEMP", "SURFAIRTEMP",                 
"TOTH2OVAP", "TOTO3", "TOTCO", "TOTCH4", "OLR_ARIS", "CLROLR_ARIS",              
"OLR_NOAA", "MODIS_LST"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `paste` the column names of 'test' with the single row of 'test', check whether `all` the elements in each `list` element are there in the `paste`d vector to get a logical vector.  Create the column by getting the `sum` and `mean` of the logical `vector`

```
v1 <- paste(names(test), unlist(test), sep="=")
i1 <- sapply(lists, function(x) all(x %in% v1))
test[c('MATCH_COUNT', 'MATCH_RATIO')] <- list(sum(i1), mean(i1))
test
#  LONGITUDE LATITUDE          DATE_START            DATE_END FLAG SURFSKINTEMP SURFAIRTEMP TOTH2OVAP TOTO3 TOTCO TOTCH4 OLR_ARIS CLROLR_ARIS OLR_NOAA MODIS_LST
#1     118.5    -11.5 2014-12-30 05:30:00 2015-01-06 05:30:00    2            6           6         6    16    13     13       10          10       10         1
#  MATCH_COUNT MATCH_RATIO
#1           3         0.5
```

---

If the dataset 'test' have greater than 1 row, then

```
m1 <- matrix(paste(names(test1)[col(test1)], unlist(test1), sep="="), ncol = ncol(test1))
i2 <- sapply(lists, function(x) apply(m1, 1, function(y) all(x %in% y)))
test1[c('MATCH_COUNT', 'MATCH_RATIO')] <- list(rowSums(i2), rowMeans(i2))
```

Comment: Thanks, if I have more than 1 rows in data.frame test, I need to count the match row by row, how to deal with multi-rows?

Comment: @Pan  In that case, you may need a rowwise, paste i.e. `apply(test, 1, function(x) paste(names(x), x, sep="="))` or so

Comment: i1 <- sapply(lists, function(x) all(x %in% v1)), this may not work right when have multi-rows

Comment: can you show me how to do rowwise in my case @akrun in this statement  
'i1 <- sapply(lists, function(x) all(x %in% v1))'

Comment: @Pan Can u update your data with one more row.  I need to test it

Comment: @Pan UPdated the answer